# Using WebBrowser in a class of a c# MVC 4 projec?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I need to open the page for the **FACEBOOK** authentication popup for the C#, but how I do this in  a secudanry class (not a controller)?

```
    private Uri GenerateLoginUrl(string extendedPermissions)
    {
        // for .net 3.5
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
         //parameters["client_id"] = appId;
        // dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters["client_id"] = this.appId;
        parameters["redirect_uri"] = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

        // The requested response: an access token (token), an authorization code (code), or both (code token).
        parameters["response_type"] = "token";

        // list of additional display modes can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display
        parameters["display"] = "popup";

        // add the 'scope' parameter only if we have extendedPermissions.
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extendedPermissions))
            parameters["scope"] = extendedPermissions;

        // generate the login url
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        return fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
    }
```

Most of tutorials say that we need user WebBrowser.Navigate and put the url on this function, but I can't use that.

```
webBrowser.Navigate(GenerateLoginUrl("manage_pages"));
```

Comment: Can you help us to understand the reason(s) why you do NOT want to do this in a controller?

Comment: Because I should do it a thousand times... Inside my class I  will do it only once. And this classes is called inside another.